# how can I calculate SINR between sepecific nodes?

Tags: veins

I am using omnetpp 5.4.1, veins 4.7.1 and sumo-0.30.0.
I want to calculate SINR between sepecific nodes in veins.
How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to calculate it or define it? These are two very different things...

Comment: thans mr sommer for your reply I am sorry I mean I want to calculate SINR between 2 specific node

Answer (score 0):

The "decider" part of the Phy layer module will attach a `DeciderResult80211` to every received message, which gets passed on to higher layers as control info. Part of this is the SNR, which can be obtained via `DeciderResult80211::getSnr` (see https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/src/veins/modules/phy/DeciderResult80211.h#L60)